# Initializing std::auto_ptr: "error: no match for call to ‘(std::auto_ptr<int>) (int*)’"

Tags: c++, raii, auto-ptr

I'm having trouble using `std::auto_ptr`. I try to compile the following on Ubuntu 11.10 using GCC 4.6.1, and I get the error message `error: no match for call to ‘(std::auto_ptr<int>) (int*)’`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Toy  {

public:
    std::auto_ptr<int> foo;

    Toy() {
        foo(new int(3));
    }
};

int main() {

    Toy toy;

    std::cout << *toy.foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was pretty sure a `std::auto_ptr< T >` takes in a `T*` as its constructor arguments, but apparently not... My apologies if this is a trivial or duplicate question, but I searched the archives, and haven't found an answer. Places like [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/auto_ptr.html) seem to suggest that the above code should work. Anyway, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize the fields of a class you use the initialization list syntax:

```
class Toy  {

public:
    std::auto_ptr<int> line;

    Toy() : line(new int(3))
    {

    }
};
```

otherwise, you may get a default-initialized `line` and reseat it with its `reset` method:

```
class Toy  {

public:
    std::auto_ptr<int> line;

    Toy()
    {
        line.reset(new int(3));
    }
};
```

But there are more problems with this code; first of all, `new int(3)` does not create an array of three `int`s (as I think you think), but it creates a single `int` initialized to `3`. What you probably meant was `new int[3]`.

*But*: `new int[3]` would need a `delete[]` to be freed, but `auto_ptr` uses plain `delete`, i.e. it's not intended to manage arrays. This because the solution provided by the standard library to manage arrays is `std::vector`, which you should probably use instead of your homebrew solution, since `std::vector` has virtually no overhead over a "normal" dynamic array.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the reset function! I think that's what I may need. And I meant new int(3). This isn't the code I'm having problems with, this is just a toy example I came up with to test it, and I needed a value for the int to print to the screen.

Comment: @anjruu: ok, then keep just the first part of the answer. It's just that a `new int(3)` assigned to a field named `line` ringed an alarm bell in my head about that potential misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh, damn, you're totally right. I forgot to change that from the original code, thanks. I'll edit that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your trouble isn't with `auto_ptr`, but with constructors in C++. You need to *initialize* class members in the constructor initializer list:

```
Toy() : line(new int(3)) { }
```

Note that this creates a single dynamic `int` with value `3`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling a constructor. Instead, you try to call a non-existent function-call operator. These would call the constructor:

```
Toy() : line(new int(3)) {
```

or (not exactly what you want)

```
Toy() {
    auto_ptr<int> line(new int(3));
```

or (as above, not what you want)

```
Toy() {
    auto_ptr<int>(new int(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not where you construct member variables.  You want to use an initializer list.

```
Toy() 
    : line(new int(3))
{ }
```

Members are constructed *just before* your classes constructor code runs.  You can assign them in the constructor code though.  They are constructed in the order they appear in the class definition, *not in the order they appear in this list*.  Most compilers will warn you if this list is out of order, just because that avoids confusion.  You can also construct parent objects in the same way, by using the parent class' type (since it has no name)

```
class Toy : public Thing {
   Toy() : Thing("APPLE") {}
};
```